# how can i set scrollviewer speed phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, scrollview

I need to slow down the speed of scrollviewer when the user lifts his/her finger from the touch screen.

How can I do that?

Now my canvas moves too quikly after the user stops scrolling the canvas (canvas with multiple images).

Here's my code:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scroller" Height="800" Width="480" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

  <Canvas Visibility="Visible" Name="canvas_images" Height="12000" Width="12000" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >

  </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the scrolling speed of the user. If you scroll it slowly, canvas moves according to it. When you scroll faster you see a fast scrolling of canvas.

We cannot control the speed of ScrollViewer.